# Uk visa application rejected

Tags: uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I applied for a standard visitors visa in august 2018 to enable me sit for Plab part 2 exams however my application was rejected on grounds of funds parking,having a bloated account and lack of evidence of proper ties to home country.
A year later I have taken steps to correct this error however the hospital I work for pays without payslips and I have to deposit my salary directly into my bank account which now shows regular deposits  for the past 6 months. 
If I apply for a standard visitors visa again with a bank statement showing regular cash deposits but not stating where the cash comes from as I have to pay it in myself,do I stand a good chance of being successful? I had previously provided a letter of introduction from my employer stating terms of my employment which I intend to submit again.

Comment: Do you have separate evidence of your job and salary? In any case, you should explain the deposits as being your regular pay, rather than leaving them unexplained.

Comment: @Chinenye Anekwe Can you provide a tax return to corroborate your salary? Why a ‘letter of introduction’ from your employer and not a contract of employment?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92121/22140